# Best solution for TLD plus a subdomain of that TLD on a WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Old hand with WordPress and a lot of multi-site experience here.  But I am chewing on best way to route a subdomain of a TLD already domain mapped on the MS installation.

EXAMPLE:  TLD is A-Recorded to the WP multi-site via IP and correctly resolves.  Say it is MAPASITE.com and that is correctly finding the right blog.  Now if I want to next map a subdomain of that TLD -- say subdomain.MAPASITE.com -- to a page on the blog, what is the best way to do so?

I thought about .htaccess and 301 redirects but am not sure if there might be a simpler c-Record or forwarding method direct from the Registrar?   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for wordpress pages aswell but you can make virtualhosts in your apache installation and set a different document root for a subdomain. I use this, but I don't use wordpress.

In case this might solve it: to change the documentroot (where the user lands when visiting a domain) just make a new .conf file in the directory where your apache installation stores its configs. These lines should do it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www
Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/somemap
ServerName subdomain.example.com
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/someerrorlog
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/someaccesslog combined
Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

You can skip the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` parts if you don't want a separate errorlog and accesslog for the subdomain.
The first `<virtualhost>` is to set the default documentroot, just point it to whatever it now is. Since you use a MS installation it certainly is different since mine is from a Debian install.

I hope this gives a solution to your problem.